# R Dataframe column to list of smaller size like in Python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, memory, data-structures

I am working with a dataframe of 1006150 rows and 3 columns, where each row contains the abstract of a wikipedia resource:

```
>>> print(df)
                                individual                                           abstract               type
0                       -ismist_Recordings  "-ismist Recordings was founded in 1992 as -is...        RecordLabel
1                          –30–_(The_Wire)  ""–30–" is the series finale of the HBO origin...  TelevisionEpisode
2                                      !!!  "!!! is a dance-punk band that formed in Sacra...               Band
3                              !!!_(album)  "!!! is the eponymous debut studio album by ro...              Album
4                     !Arriba!_La_Pachanga  "!Arriba! La Pachanga is an album by Mongo San...              Album
```

The goal is to vectorize the abstract column in order to feed a text model.

The problem is that in R, when i try to do get the abstracts list to perform this conversion i end with a variable of large size (around **800 MB**), this leads to run out of memory when i try to run the vectorizer. I have tried quanteda's dfm() and TfIdfVectorizer from superml package. With quanteda i got a dfm of size 2 Gb (too large to train the model) and superml package throws an error out-of-memory:

```
> df <- read.csv(file="t.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
> abstracts_list <- df$abstract
> object.size(abstracts_list)
806675688 bytes
```

```
> library("superml")
Loading required package: R6
> tf <- TfIdfVectorizer$new()
> tf$fit_transform(abstracts_list)
Error: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño  7822.6 Gb
```

The curious thing is that in python I don't have this problem, after loading the data and extracting the list of abstracts, the variable weighs about **8 MB**.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
df = pd.read_csv("t.csv")
train_data = df['abstract'].tolist()
sys.getsizeof(train_data)
>>> sys.getsizeof(df['abstract'])
1093787258
>>> sys.getsizeof(train_data)
8049256
```

It seems that in python, converting a column into a list with numpy.ndarray.tolist reduces the size considerably (R=800MB, Py=8MB), **is there a similar method in R that allows me to convert a column of a dataframe into a list of smaller size?**

Note: in both python and R scripts i have used the same csv file.
Note 2: Unlike R in python I can use TfidfVectorizer without any problem (sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer)

Comment: After some research I came to the conclusion that these memory problems are due to the way R loads everything into memory, unlike python which uses pointers (I'm not 100% sure about this). I understand that the low weight of variables is because they are actually pointers, not variables per se. Because of all this I have asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661640/process-quanteda-objects-even-larger-than-available-memory