# Process quanteda objects even larger than available memory

Tags: r, memory, nlp, dbpedia, quanteda

I am working with a dataframe of 1006150 rows and 3 columns, where each row contains the abstract of a wikipedia resource:

```
>>> print(df)
                                individual                                           abstract               type
0                       -ismist_Recordings  "-ismist Recordings was founded in 1992 as -is...        RecordLabel
1                          –30–_(The_Wire)  ""–30–" is the series finale of the HBO origin...  TelevisionEpisode
2                                      !!!  "!!! is a dance-punk band that formed in Sacra...               Band
3                              !!!_(album)  "!!! is the eponymous debut studio album by ro...              Album
4                     !Arriba!_La_Pachanga  "!Arriba! La Pachanga is an album by Mongo San...              Album
```

The goal is to vectorize the abstract column in order to feed a text model.

The problem is that in R, when i try to do get the abstracts list to perform this conversion i end with a variable of large size (around 800 MB), this leads to run out of memory when i try to run the vectorizer or the model. I have tried quanteda's dfm() and TfIdfVectorizer from superml package. With quanteda i got a dfm of size 1.6 Gb (too large to train the model) and superml package throws an error out-of-memory:

```
> df <- read.csv(file="t.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
> abstracts_list <- df$abstract
> object.size(abstracts_list)
806675688 bytes
> my_corpus <- corpus(df, text_field = "abstract", docid_field = "individual")
> tdm <- dfm(my_corpus, tolower=FALSE)
> tdm <- dfm_tfidf(tdm)
> object.size(tdm)
1572794560 bytes
```

```
> library("superml")
Loading required package: R6
> tf <- TfIdfVectorizer$new()
> tf$fit_transform(abstracts_list)
Error: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño  7822.6 Gb
```

If i try to train the model with the 1.9Gb dfm this happens:

```
> tmod <- textmodel_svm(tdm, y = tdm$type, weight = "uniform", verbose=TRUE)
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

This problem does not appear in Python so I understand that it is because R is trying to load everything in memory. I have tried the ff package but it didn't work for me or I didn't know how to use it. Is there any method to deal with this problem?

Update: I have also tried to vectorize with word2vec and used LibLineaR model (which is the library that textmodel_svm of quanteda uses) and the problem is that i can not fit the model in memory, i get the Cholmod error. Is there any other package memory friendly to make svm models like LibLinear?

Update2: In the dfm i am working with rn has 1006150 documents and 1716098 features. I am only working with 33% of the data, I would also like to be able to test with 3000000 documents even though at the moment it seems impossible. In my local machine i have 32 Gb of RAM

Update 3: To reproduce the error i uploaded the dfm to drive and can be downloaded and tested with the following code:

```
library("quanteda")
library("quanteda.textmodels")
library(googledrive)
temp_rds_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds")
d_rds_file <- drive_download(
  as_id("1E4ZPUbR98vLW5hmL0GYYQ-GYPDP7vriR"), path = temp_r_file, overwrite = TRUE)
tdm <- readRDS(d_rds_file$local_path)
tmod <- textmodel_svm(tdm, y = tdm$type, weight = "uniform", verbose=TRUE)
```

Comment: I don't think is not going to be able to handle fitting a model with that size input matrix, even a sparse one. But it would help to know the number of features. You can try using `dfm_trim()` to reduce it, and/or use Naive Bayes instead, which is fast and robust.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently i am trying to reproduce a Python software in R in order to perform some upgrades. Unfortunately the objective of this work is to reproduce a software written in Python and then make some performance improvements. In the original work it does not reduce the number of features and uses svm (sklearn LinearSVC which uses LibLineaR). Anyways thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

After several days investigating this problem I have found out why it fails.

Apparently the function textmodel_svm internally tries to eliminate the constant columns (non-variance features) by calculating the variance of each feature.
To calculate the variance R transforms the dfm into a matrix and when doing this transformation, the [Cholmod library](https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/blob/master/CHOLMOD/Core/cholmod_dense.c) makes sure that it will not produce an Integer overflow with the number of columns and the leading dimension (leading dimensions >= num rows).

I posted a comment in an open thread about this, more info [here](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.textmodels/issues/23#issuecomment-853777401):
https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.textmodels/issues/23#issuecomment-853777401